# How can I find matching items between a dictionary and a list to create a new list from the matches?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have two sets of data - a dictionary (data) and a list (list_1) both of unequal lengths. I would like to iterate through both and do the following:

1. If the item in list_1 matches the key data add the value to a 2nd list.
2. If the item is not in the dictionary add "NULL" instead

Th 3rd list should be the same length as list_1

Here is the sample code:

```py
a = ['dim','john','joey','tron','bob','wilt','kobe']
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
data = dict(zip(a,b))

list_1 = ['bob','sue','mike','willy','john','may','beth','wilt']

list_2 = []

for x in list_1:
    for key,value in data.items():
        if x in key:
            list_2.append(key)
        elif x not in key:
            list_2.append("NULL")
```

The results of this would be

```
['NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'bob', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'john', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'wilt', 'NULL']
```

Is it possible to make the 3rd list show as the following?

```
['bob','NULL','NULL','NULL','john','NULL','NULL','wilt']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by simply checking if the value is in the keys of the dictionary.

```
list_1 = ['bob','sue','mike','willy','john','may','beth','wilt']
list_2 = []

for x in list_1:
    if x in data.keys():
        list_2.append(x)
    else:
        list_2.append("NULL")
```

If you want to be fancy and concise, you can use a list comprehension.

```
list_2 = [x if x in data.keys() else "NULL" for x in list_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just scroll through the list once.

```
for x in list_1:
    if x in list(data.keys()):
        list_2.append(x)
    else:
        list_2.append('NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the length of your output by using function len(), you would get 56=length_of_list1(8)*length_of_data(7). But you only need list 2 the same length of list1, so you may see that the loop `for key,value in data.items():`is redundant. You may use the`find`function in dictionary `if x in data.keys():`to check, no need to check x with k one by one.